# Samba server connected to WLAN router cannot access Windows machines connected to netgear hub

Tags: router, samba, switch

I have a samba linux server connected to the WLAN router. Also connected to the WLAN router is a netgear hub/switch that is itself connected to the office windows workstations. The problem is that the windows workstations cannot seem to see the Samba server on the Windows Workgroup network.

The firewall on the WLAN router is off and the samba server is accessible (via ssh) from the rest of the internet.

The samba server has an external static IP assigned by the ISP. It's not an internal LAN 192.168.100.x address, could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Windows networking is broadcast based and, as such, won't traverse subnets over a router. I suggest accessing the SAMBA share from the LAN computers via the public static IP address of the server and cutting NetBios out of the equation.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I decided to put the samba server within the same subnet (ie router) as the LAN computers.